# Whats the Theory behind capital letters in Java Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been learning Java now and i am struggling to get the grips of when i use capital letters for various different things.

For Instance:

```
  Button buttonname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
```

**"find"** and **R."id"** doesnt have capital yet the **"View" "By"** and **"Id"** does 
also :

```
   buttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

In the line above **"set"** doesnt have a capital but the rest does including **"On"** ??
Then you have :

```
 String.valueOf()
```

with the value not having a capital v.

So i was wondering is there a method to where these capitals are required/not required etc as im constantly getting syntax wrong due to these kinds of capitalization.

Cheers

Comment: Anyone else wanna add a minus i have very little reputation for you to take ... so take it all you want..... this community is extremely fickle and unaccomodating for newbies.... shame really.

Comment: Don't let down votes get you down.  It's not bullying it means the question doesn't belong here or it's too simple.  On the bright side you've mastered how to format your questions format code and format bold.  I saw a good answer below it starts out in java classes are upper camel case.  I'll give you an up vote because you formatted the question perfectly.

Comment: Thank you danny!!!!! You have restored my faith :)

Answer (score 6):

In java classes are upper camel case, so;

```
UpperCamelCase
```

Variable names are lower camel case, so;

```
lowerCamelCase
```

Methods are also lower camel case, so;

```
lowerCamelCase()
```

#### Specific examples

```
Button buttonname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
```

Button is a class, so is UpperCamelCase, buttonname is a variable name so **should be** buttonName in lower camel case. R is a class so is in UpperCamelCase, id and buttonid are variables so are lowerCamelCase (id in  buttonid  is lower case because its not really a word, so is somewhat of a grey area; although I would have used buttonID.

```
buttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

buttonname is a variable, setOnClickListener is a method which is again lowerCamelCase, and View.OnClickListener is a class so is again UpperCamelCase

See [The official naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: Thanks for that it explains all.... people too quick to give minus here it sucks.... Anyway thanks for the link, its hard to find these kinds of answers when your not sure of the search criteria you a looking for. People dont seem to take that into account. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

See java naming conventions link below, all cases you describe above are explained. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 0):

These are the Java naming conventions. Class must begin with a Capital letter, whereas variables and methods begins with small letters..

Moreover, when multiple words are used for eg `onClick()` then camel cases are used with each letter of the next word capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a part of the language, but it is a kind of standart for naming variables and function. The first word isn't capitalized, and all the other soes.

For class names, all of the words starts is capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

These are standard Java naming conventions, and every programming language has its own set of recommended conventions.

In Java, camel case (e.g. oneTwoThree) is recommended when naming functions, variables, and classes etc. Classes start with capital letters (e.g. *Button*), and functions/variables begin with a lower case letter (e.g. *buttonname* or *findViewById()*). Keep in mind that there are other conventions too where this may deviate (i.e. constants or static methods), but again it is all a part of the naming conventions for Java.

For example:

```
Button buttonname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
```

- **Button** is the name of a class so it has a capital letter, whereas **buttonname** is an instance of that class (variable name), so it is given a lowercase (though if you want to follow the conventions it
  should be written in camel case, i.e. buttonName).
- **findViewById** is a function, so it begins with a lowercase and follows camel-case for the sake of readability (easier to read that
  than findviewbyid).

Read more on the theory [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29).

When all is said and done, there is nothing stopping somebody from breaking the conventions, but you should follow them to enhance code readability for yourself and others who may encounter your source code, and to reduce the effort taken to understand your program.